# How can I create MySQL table that contain two columns?

Tags: java

I want create MySQL table that contain two columns in java , with the name of columns enter by user ?

Answer (score 2):

First you are gonna have to connect to the database, and then you can excecute queries:

```
 System.out.println("Table Creation Example!");
 Connection con = null;
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
 String dbName = "jdbctutorial";
 String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
 String userName = "root";
 String password = "root";
 String column1 = "nameOfTheFirstColumn";
 String column2 = "nameOfTheSecondColumn";

 try{
  Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
 con = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userName, password);
 try{
  Statement st = con.createStatement();
  String table = 
  "CREATE TABLE Employee11(column1 + " varchar(10), + column2 + "Emp_name varchar(10))";
  st.executeUpdate(table);
  System.out.println("Table creation process successfully!");
  }
  catch(SQLException s){
  System.out.println("Table all ready exists!");
  }
  con.close();
  }
  catch (Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Adapted from this [source](http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/CreateTable.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

First get the column names using `Scanner`. Now for creating the table with these column name

```
  Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
  String createTable = 
  "CREATE TABLE NEWTABLE(" + inputName1 + "varchar(100), " + inputName2 + " varchar(100))";
  statement.executeUpdate(createTable);
```